# Is it a bug of acmart or hyperref that the acmart class is incompatible with tikzexternalize and lualatex under some unclear conditions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, tikz-external, acmart

I'm very confused by this error, and in particular how sensitive it is to things like the number of characters in section titles, and whether or not I stick any space between `\begin{abstract}` and `\end{abstract}`.

Consider the following document in `test.tex`:

```latex
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\title{}
\begin{abstract} \end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{XXXXXXXXX}\subsection{X XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX}\subsection{XXXXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX}\subsection{XXX XXXXXXXX}
\section{XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXX}\subsection{XXX XXXXXXXX XX XXXX XXXXX}
\section{XXX XXXXXXXXX XX X XXXXXXXX}\subsection{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXX}
\subsection{XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX}
\section{XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX}\subsection{XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX XX XXXXX}\subsection{XXXXXXX XXXXXXX XX XXXXXXX}
\subsection{XXXXX XXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXXX}\subsection{XXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\subsection{XXXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\section{XXXXXXXXXX}\subsection{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [color=black,solid,line width=1.0pt,domain=0:1,samples=11]{x+x^2};
        \addlegendentry{Eq. \ref{eq:equation}};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subsubsection{XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXX}\subsubsection{XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX XX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX}
\subsubsection{XXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX}\subsubsection{XXXX XXXXXXXXX}\subsection{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX}
\section{XXXXXXX XXXX}
\section{XXXXXX XXXX}
\end{document}
```

Running `rm -f test-* test.a* test.b* test.p* test.s* test.o* test.l*; lualatex -shell-escape test.tex` gives a log that ends with

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `TotPages' on page 1 undefined on input line 10.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg)
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjo
b{test}\input{test}"' ========
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
 system commands enabled.
LaTeX Warning: External picture `test-figure0' contains undefined references on
 input line 24.

===== The previous system call resulted in undefined references inside of the o
utput file. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active

LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastPage' on page 1 undefined on input line 24.

[1.1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2.2<./test-figure0.pd
f>] [3.3] (./test.aux

Package atenddvi Warning: Rerun LaTeX, last page not yet found.

)
===== tikzexternal: \end{document} reached. Working on rescheduled images to re
solve references... ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjo
b{test}\input{test}"' ========
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
 system commands enabled.

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{t
est}\input{test}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'test-figure0' (expec
ted one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system c
alls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also name
d 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error
messages can be found in 'test-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to t
ypeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.28 \end{document}

?
```

The proximate cause of this error is that, at this point, the contents of `test.out` ends with

```
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.6}{\376\377\0006\000\040\000X\000X\000X\000X\000X\000X\000X\000\040\000X\000X\000X\000X}{}% 20
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.7}{\376\377\0007\000\040\000X\000X\000X\000X\000X\000X\000\040\000X\000X\000X\000X}{
```

Yes, it ends in the middle of a `\BOOKMARK`, as suggested by the error in `test-figure0.log`:

```
(./test.out)
Runaway argument?
{
! File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK.
<inserted text>
\par
l.7 \begin{document}
```

I have no idea why this happens (and I'd like to understand), but what's even stranger is the small changes that result in the code passing fine.  A non-exhaustive list:

- I think that replacing any instance of `X X` with either `XX` in the document (removing a single space in any of the section titles) makes the error go away.  (I'm not patient enough to test this, but I tried three different instances and all three made the error go away.)
- I think that removing any `X` (shortening the length of any title by one) results in the code passing fine.  (Again, I'm not patient enough to test this, but I tried three different instances and all three made the error go away.)
- In some instances, replacing `X X` with `XXX` (replacing a single space with an `X` in the section titles) results in the error going away (in other places it does not).
- Removing the space between `\begin{abstract}` and `\end{abstract}` makes the error go away.

Somewhat more importantly:

- Using `pdflatex` rather than `lualatex` makes the error go away (but I cannot use `pdflatex` in my real example because some of my plots are too big)
- Using `article` rather than `acmart` makes the error go away, but the conference I'm submitting to requires acmart.

I've reported this [as a bug on acmart](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/436), but I'm not at all sure that it is a bug in that package, given how fragile the conditions are for hitting it; it seems like it might just as well be a bug in the interaction of hyperref and tikzexternalize that is only revealed by something acmart does.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: I get the expected result if I add an equation for the cross reference and also `\usepackage{bookmark}`.

Comment: I would also suggest bookmark, then hyperref won't try to write the out-file and there is less danger for clashes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is not a clash; the .out file is correctly written when the pass finishes.  The issue is that the .out file is only partially written (maybe a missing flush?) at the point at which tikzexternalize tries to rerun the document, and hence it is read in when in an invalid state.

@egreg Indeed, `\usepackage{bookmark}` results in there being no .out file.  I'm still interested in understanding what exactly is going wrong here.

Comment: How would you check if there are 2+ anchors/destinations with the same name string?

Comment: It's trying to make cross-references using the section text (presumably on the assumption such things are unique). When I make the section headings unique (adding an `a`, `b`, etc), it produces a ...figure0.pdf file (with a ?? Equation reference in the legend, of course). Unrelated: what is `luatex85` for? It runs OK without it, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Cicada The bug is very sensitive to text length, I'm not surprised that *adding* a character to each section heading removes the bug.  If instead I *replace* the first character of each section heading with a unique letter (`a` through `x`, unless I missed one), the bug persists.  See https://github.com/JasonGross/test-latex-errors/blob/439481516ce447fcb6a1306f3613571d2e5d6e51/test.tex

Comment: The `luatex85` package is cargo-culted from other projects where I've had some files build fine on my machine in lualatex but error on a co-worker's machine in lualatex, and `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` solved it.  I can't find the discussion where we originally solved the problem, I don't recall the error message, and the commit message that introduced it just says "compatibility fixes", unfortunately.  Since the behavior was different on different machines (presumably different TeXLive distributions), I tend to just leave it in whenever I'm using lualatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tikz picture contains a reference and so tikz reschedules the compilation in the `enddocument/afteraux` hook:

```
===== tikzexternal: \end{document} reached. Working on rescheduled images to re
solve references... ========
```

This rescheduled compilation also reads in auxiliary files. That is ok for the aux-file which has already been closed, but can be a problem for other auxiliary files. Not every one has been explicitly closed until then: often packages simply let the end of the compilation automatically close a file.

Here the problem is the out-file from hyperref: the version from the main compilation is still open and it is in a more or less random state depending on conditions like timing and pagebreaks and when the rescheduled compilation reads it in again it can breaks (or not).

One could force hyperref to close the file by adding (before loading tikz)

```
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{enddocument/afteraux}[hyperref]{\@ifundefined{@outlinefile}{}{\immediate\closeout\@outlinefile}}
\makeatother
```

An alternative suggested by muzimuzhi in https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1127 would be to suppress the bookmarks for the externalized graphics (where they don't make sense anyway) with

```
\tikzset{external/system call={%
  pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image"
  "\string\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks=false}{hyperref}\texsource"}}
```

Both solutions only handle the `.out`-file, similar clashes with other files are still possible.